# About Linq left join

Tags: linq

```
select A.Name,B.UserId
from [dbo].[SentryBoxs] as A
left join [dbo].[SentryBoxUsers] as B on A.ID = B.SentryBoxId
and B.UserId = '970500c2-51bd-443e-ae10-585455f2b326'
```

[image: [enter image description here][]

[image]

How to implement by linq???

Comment: Answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Is very helpful to me. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var ans = from A in dboSentryBoxs
          join B in dboSentryBoxUsers on new { A.ID, UserID = "970500c2-51bd-443e-ae10-585455f2b326" } equals new { ID = B.SentryBoxId, B.UserID } into Bjoin
          from B in Bjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { A.Name, B.UserID };
```